# Grub installed over refit after installing ubuntu 12.04 on imac7,1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mac, refit

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my old imac7,1.

The first thing I did was install refit from OSX. After that, I installed ubuntu from a liveCD and all went apparently fine.

The problem is that GRUB shows up instead of refit and there's no way to boot OSX because when I choose OSX from the grub menu nothing occurs.

I have found this topic that seems to talk about this problem but it's my first ubuntu installation on a mac computer and I don't want to mess the things up.

[Ubuntu installed GRUB over rEFIt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301245/ubuntu-installed-grub-over-refit)

And also this is the answer given from **iamwpj**, that seems to be my solution but I don't know how to do it.

> I actually figured this out. The easiest way in any situation where
>   GRUB overwrites rEFIt is to hit C when the GRUB screen loads. This
>   will bring up the grub command line. Typing exit here will exit GRUB
>   and show you rEFIt. From here a boot into OSX will allow you to
>   uninstall GRUB and install rEFInd.

Should I uninstall GRUB from ubuntu? And, after that, will refit show up?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it's finally working installing refind. Now the problem is that I have to bootloaders (Refind and then Grub if I choose ubuntu). Is there a more elegant way to hide Grub than changing the timeout to 1 second? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up rEFInd to boot Linux directly. Chances are all you need to do is to install the EFI filesystem driver for whatever filesystem holds your kernel (probably ext4fs). You can do this in OS X by creating an `/EFI/refind/drivers` directory and copying the relevant driver file (such as `ext4_x64.efi`) from the rEFInd package to the new directory. (This assumes a default installation of rEFInd from OS X; if you used the `--ownhfs` or `--esp` option, rEFInd will be located somewhere other than `/EFI/refind`.) Once you've set this up, you may also want to run the `mkrlconf.sh` script, which comes with rEFInd, in Linux. This isn't absolutely required in most cases, although it is necessary for some configurations. The biggest change you'll see is a switch from verbose boot with text-mode boot messages to the more familiar graphical boot with an Ubuntu logo on the screen.